# What's integral of $\frac1x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)$

Tags: integration

> What is the integral of $$\frac1x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)?$$

I know the integral of $\sin\left(\dfrac1x\right)$ does not have answer with normal integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x>0$, $$\int\frac{\sin\dfrac1x}xdx=-\int\frac{t\sin t}{t^2}dt=-\int\text{sinc }t\,dt.$$

The antiderivative of the Cardinal Sine is known as the Integral Sine. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral